# SingleScroll Horizontal Gridview - One item at a time

Tags: java, android, gridview, scrollable

I have a horizontal gridview and i want it so when you scroll, only one item will be displayed at a time.
One item has the width of the screen so when you slide to the left i want it to smoothly scroll to the next item.

Also, if you scroll one item to half it should go back to that item.

I am pretty stuck now, thank you!

```
public class FrameGridAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FrameGridAdapter.SimpleViewHolder>{

public static final String BUTTON_UPLOAD = "0x111";

private Context context;
private List<FRData> elements;

public FrameGridAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<FRData> data){
    this.context = context;
    this.elements = data;
}

public static class SimpleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public final TextView txt_fNo;
    public final ImageView img_frame_bm;

    public SimpleViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        txt_fNo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_edit_frame_no);
        img_frame_bm = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_edit_frame);
    }
}

@Override
public SimpleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    final View view = LayoutInflater.from(this.context).inflate(R.layout.grid_frames_item, parent, false);
    return new SimpleViewHolder(view);
}

public void onBindViewHolder(SimpleViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.txt_fNo.setText("Frame #" + elements.get(position).frame_no);
    holder.img_frame_bm.setImageBitmap(elements.get(position).frame_bm);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return this.elements.size();
}
```

}

```
private void DisplayFramesForEdit() {
    ArrayList<FRData> frames_list = new ArrayList<FRData>();

    for (Bitmap bm: last15shots) {
        try
        {
            FRData frame_temp = new FRData();
            frame_temp.frame_bm = bm;
            frame_temp.frame_no = last15shots.indexOf(bm);

            frames_list.add(frame_temp);
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    FrameGridAdapter fr_adapter;
    fr_adapter = new FrameGridAdapter(VideoEditorActivity.this, frames_list);

    frames_grid.setAdapter(fr_adapter);
}
```

Here is the code.

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: @Sonam Done, i have edited the main thread.